# Running a python program stored in a shell variable

Tags: python, bash, shell

I want write a shell script that will run a Python Code stored in a shell variable `$CODE`.

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 $CODE
```

But this does not work, is there any way to do this? Any help is appreciated.The program that will be run:

```
print("Hello World")
export CODE='print("Hello World")'
```

Comment: You should have gotten an error message with your approach, something like "can't open file ....".

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-c` option.

```bash
python3 -c "$CODE"
```

Answer (score 1):

[[Python.Docs]: Command line and environment - -c <command>](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-c) states:

> Execute the Python code in *command*. *command* can be one or more statements separated by newlines, with significant leading whitespace as in normal module code.

Example:

> ```
> [064bit prompt]> CODE='import sys;print("Hello World");print(sys.version)'
> [064bit prompt]> python -c "${CODE}"
> Hello World
> 3.8.10 (default, Jun 22 2022, 20:18:18)
> [GCC 9.4.0]
> ```

But this comes with some limitations. I'd save the code in a script and run that instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
python3 <<< "$CODE"
```